# google+ sign in api, sending access tokens over http?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, ssl, cors

Hello unfortunately the site I am working on has no SSL certificate or anything (Kinda stupid but nothing I can do). I am implementing google+ sign in on the site and the JavaScript is all working, I get the access token back and everything as well.

The Problem is when it comes time to send the data off to the server for verification before signing a user in, is it ok to send the access token over HTTP or do I NEED SSL for that. I have tried getting CORS to work with Ajax but I keep getting a

> "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows
>   reading the remote resource at
>   https://www.mysite.com/Store/google_login. This can be fixed by
>   moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS."

It works over over HTTP obviously but I have no idea how to get it working using HTTPS, it just keeps bringing back that same error.

I tried putting these headers at the beginning of the google_login function, even tried it with .httaccess instead and still nothing.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.mysite.com");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Cache-Control, X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, X-File-Name, X-File-Size");
```

So any ideas on what to do? Can I just use HTTP, maybe somehow encrypt it before sending it, I doubt it but I don't know what else to do to get cors working, the server has no SSL certificate by the way, could that be the problem? I have no way to fix that either unfortunately

Comment: You **must** use HTTPS for the whole site, or attackers can modify your JS to steal the tokens for themselves.

Comment: you shouldn't need a cert on the client side, unless whatever you're requires you to securely identify yourself to google. you should be able to just point curl/php at the https url and go from there.

Comment: Well I was looking and it looks like i could just use this one instead for the sign in https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow. Google sends back a one time use code which you then pass to the server at which time the server exchanges for a access token. It seems from there examples at least that ssl would not be needed for the client-server call. Only the client-google and server-google call would need SSL which I can already do. So is this an acceptable way to go about it?